# What's the relationship between UIView and CALayer

Tags: cocoa-touch, design-patterns, uiview, calayer

So here is my understanding: there is a `setNeedsDisplay` in both UIView and CALayer class, UIView is a composite class that includes a CALayer. But UIView uses `drawRect:` while CALayer uses `drawLayer:inContext:` They both use `setNeedsDisplay` to call it. Is this some protocol or something? So I guess at some point in the implementation of UIView, a CALayer is created and this layer's delegate is set to the UIView class? What's exactly the relationship between this two classes? So the `drawRect:` in UIView is basically parsing it's content and call `drawLayer:inContext:` of its layer? What kind of design pattern is this? I'm trying to wrap my head around how these two classes work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is all Apple's implementation detail so I don't know for sure.  Also, different view classes will have different relationships with their layer.

For example, `UIImageView` is [explicitly documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to *not* call `drawRect:`.  This is probably because setting an image actually updates the layer's `contents` property directly without going through the rendering methods.

That said, I imagine most basic `UIView` behavior is that `setNeedsDisplay` simply forwards the call to the layer.  Then, when the `drawLayer:inContext:` is called on the view, it sets up the `UIGraphics` context stuff and calls `drawRect:`.